# How do I specify table order with sync framework when using sync orchestrator

Tags: .net, microsoft-sync-framework, data-synchronization

I'm using sync framework with SyncOrchestrator and SqlSyncProvider. My problem is that the updates are applied in the incorrect order. I have a many to many relationship. Let's say I have 3 tables `Students` `Courses` `StudentsCourses`, it first tries to insert rows into the 3rd table `StudentsCourses` even if the student doesn't exist. It should do an insert for a student (or course) first and then an insert into studentsCourses. How can I do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

the order in which tables are synched is the order in which they were added to the scope.

in your case, you should add Students, Courses and StudentsCourses in that order to the scope.

Comment: They are added in that order

Comment: can you enable Sync Fx tracing and post a trace?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Can you explain please.

Comment: Also is there a difference between sync fx and sync framework or are they the same?